# Finding minimal polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, algebraic-numbers

We note $m(x)=(x^2-2)^2-3$.

$m(x)$ is a polynomial vanishing at $\alpha=\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3}}$.

But how to prove that $m(x)$ is the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $\mathbb{Q}$?

Thanks

Comment: How familiar are you with the theory of field extensions?

Comment: we started know a cours in Galois theory. But i am not able to answer the question, please help me

Answer (score 1):

It is easy to see that the other roots of $m(x)$ are $\sqrt{2-\sqrt3}$ and $-\sqrt{2-\sqrt3}$. If $m(x)$ was not the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt{2+\sqrt3}$, then it would be reducible in$\mathbb{Q}[x]$. Since $\deg m(x)=4$, we would then be able to express it either as a product of two quadratic polynomials is a the product of a first degree polynonial with a cubic one. This second possibility cannot take place, since $m(x)$ has no rational roots. And if $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are any two distinct roots of $m(x)$, it is easy to show that $(x-\alpha)(x-\beta)\notin\mathbb{Q}[x]$.

Comment: ''it is easy to show that $(x-\alpha)(x-\beta)\notin\mathbb{Q}[x]$''  to show that we only say that $\alpha.\beta\notin \mathbb{Q}$??

Comment: @moona Note that $\sqrt{2+\sqrt3}.\sqrt{2-\sqrt3}=1\in\mathbb Q$.

Comment: so why $(x-\alpha)(x-\beta)\notin\mathbb{Q}[x]$ is true?

Comment: @moona Because $\sqrt{2+\sqrt3}+\sqrt{2-\sqrt3}\notin\mathbb Q$.

Comment: ok and i want to show that $ L=Q(α)$ is a normal extension of $Q$. For that i need to prove that the Galois group for this extension is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z_2}\times\mathbb{Z_2}$ can you please help me to do so?

Comment: @moona Because, if $\alpha=\sqrt{2+\sqrt3}$ and $\beta=\sqrt{2-\sqrt3}$, then the coefficient of $x$ in $(x-\alpha)(x-\beta)$ is $-\bigl(\sqrt{2+\sqrt3}+\sqrt{2-\sqrt3}\bigr)$.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a different solution:

If we know that $m(x)$ is irreducible, then we know that it is the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$. Since $m(x+1) = x^4 + 4x^3 + 2x^2 - 4x - 2$ is irreducible by Eisenstein's criterion, $m(x)$ is irreducible.

Answer (score 0):

The polynomial $m$ has no rational roots, because its constant term is $1$ and neither $1$ nor $-1$ is a root.

If $m$ is reducible, it must be a product of degree two factors; hence $\alpha=\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3}}$ has degree $2$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. Since $\sqrt{3}=\alpha^2-2\in\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$, we conclude that $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3})$, by the dimension formula. Hence, for some $x,y\in\mathbb{Q}$,
$$
\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3}}=x+y\sqrt{3}
$$
Square, compare and find a contradiction.